# Bottom bar in NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developing an app in Cocoa. I need to show a progress at the bottom bar of window. But I am searching for a solution to put a bottom bar in a `NSWindow`.

Looking forward for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom's answer is correct, but also take a look at [BWToolKit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/). It includes a few nice controls for working with bottom bars.

Comment: The answer below is a far better one, especially since BWToolKit won't work in Xcode 4's interface builder.

Answer (score 43):

This is the code to put a bar at the bottom of the window (like in the finder):

```
[theWindow setContentBorderThickness:24.0 forEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `autorecalculatesContentBorderThickness` to `NO`: http://developer.apple.com/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html

Comment: It can now also be done within the IB - under 'content border' of the window select the large or small bottom border option. Any idea though on how to get the 1px black border on top of the bottom bar?

Comment: Oops, my bad :( the 1px border is visible by default, it was just being overlapped by my view.

Comment: Well now there is the Content Boarder setting "Small Bottom Border" (22 thickness and manual flag enabled) nevertheless I have to manual setup a vertical space constraint of 22 to keep the (main)view of this window not overlapping the border or did i miss a setting?

Comment: @Stephan when I last did this, I had to do the same. I don't think the bottom border affects the size of the content view, it just changes how the background is drawn.

Comment: where is that content boarder setting?

Comment: Just in case someone else comes looking here. Click on your window, then click Size Inspector.  My question is how do you write text?  I tried adding an NSTextField to the window, but that doesn't work.  Do you place a text field at the bottom of the view, or does it need to be added programtically?

Answer (score 2):

Well technically the answer of Tom is ok. You can find some comments on this how to handle this in IB.

In general you should take a look into the [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW6). 
It recommend not to use bottom bars for new apps.

Comment: Can you point a specific link? The only occurrence I can find (using your link) is this: "If your window includes a bottom bar (which is not typical), you can use window-frame controls in the bottom bar." which does not sound like discouraging...