# Adding footer in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm developing a Cocoa application for Mac. In the application, I have to add a footer to a table for adding and deleting rows like in the attached image:

[image]

Is there any default controls present for such type of footer view?
If there is no such default control, I have to use the image.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such default control. you can create a custom control like this or you can get this effect by taking a image and two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Bottom bar in NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097115/bottom-bar-in-nswindow) for a similar problem and suggestions to solve it!