# How do I add buttons below a SourceList like in Mail.app and Things?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to add buttons below a SourceList like these:

[image: Things buttons] [image: Mail.app buttons]

How can I do this? Is there a built in control for this? Another example of similar buttons is OmniFocus, I'd be happy with this too:

[image: Omnifocus Buttons]

Comment: NSOutlineView has no concept of a footer.  You'll need to contain it in an NSView, then add that bar of buttons over top of the source list.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138211/adding-footer-in-nstableview